# Como puedo lanzar eventos desde una clase en javascript

Tags: eventos

Tengo la siguiente clase

```
Class Kline {
     constructor(){
          this.depth = new Depth(this)
     }
 }
```

la clase Depth se encarga de obtener algunos valores que se actualizan constantemente por medio de un stream por lo tanto tiene una metodo update()

```
Class Depth {
     constructor(kline) {}
     update(){}
}
```

Teniendo esto en cuenta los objetos Kline necesitan saber cuando termino de actualizar Depth para que tambien actualizen otros valores, por otro lado tengo otra clase Orderbook al que se le pasa el Kline que se acaba de crear y por tanto tambien necesita saber cuando el objeto Depth actualizo para que tambien actualize sus propios datos

```
Class Orderbook {
     constructor(kline) {}
}
```

Como puedo hacer para que Kline y Orderbook sepan cuando Depth termino de actualizar, como puedo lanzar un evento que atrapen ambos objetos, pense en algo como lo siguiente pero no funciona

```
Class Depth {
     constructor(kline){}
     update(){
          this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('depthUpdate', {bubbles:true, detail:this})
     }
}

Class Kline {
     constructor(){
          this.addEventLintener('depthUpdate', e => {...})
     }
}

Class Orderbook {
     constructor(kline){
          this.addEventLintener('depthUpdate', e => {...})
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Era tan facil como usar el dispatchEvent() y el addEventListener() sin el this